# Conditional Rendering in React - stuck on loading DIV

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

Evening/Morning All

So, for the 2nd time in as many days, I'm back on here - hat in hand. I've got this kind of condition to work so well elsewhere but here I just can't get the 'loading' div to disappear once the 'pageData' has been fully downloaded. I tried it already with if/else (which I don't normally use in this case). If anyone could cast a 2nd set of eyes over this for me I'd be very thankful.

```
import DataStore from "flux/stores/DataStore.js";

const ContentData = ({ pageData }) => {
  if (!pageData) {
    // evaluates to true if pageData is null
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Homepage template</h2>
      <h1>{pageData.title.rendered}</h1>

      <div
        className="content"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: pageData.content.rendered }}
      />
      <div>{pageData.acf.text}</div>
    </div> // render content
  );
};

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let pageData = DataStore.getPageBySlug("home");

    return (
      <div>
        <ContentData />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Ths data is definitely coming through from the Wordpress API, I can view it all in the console.

Thanks in advance

Terry

Here's the 'getPageBySlug' function

```
// Returns a Page by provided slug
getPageBySlug(slug){
    const pages = this.getState().data.pages;
    return pages[Object.keys(pages).find((page, i) => {
        return pages[page].slug === slug;
    })] || {};
  }

  }
```

Comment: you should pass `pageData` as prop to  `<ContentData pageData={pageData}/>`

Comment: Is `DataStore.getPageBySlug("home")` asynchronous?

Comment: Thaks @samee - unfortunately, it didn't work. This is the most recent of 1000 versions - I had tried it previously (and I did again) - cheers anyway!

Comment: @Tholle - I'm adding it to the question now - but no, it's not

Comment: Thanks. If it's not asynchronous, and you pass it down as a prop like samee said, the loading indicator should never be displayed. It might be that your `getPageBySlug` is wrong? Have you tried `return pages.find(page => page.slug === slug) || {};`?

Comment: Sorry @Tholle, it's not working - I have the function working elsewhere too - so I'm fairly sure that's not the issue - I needed to add the condition (I'd imagine) because the 2 WordPress sites I'm working with are a heavy data download compared to the test site where I'm already using the function.

Comment: Yes, a loading indicator is a great idea if you have some asynchronous logic in e.g. `componentDidMount` that will eventually set some component state that you use as props for `ContentData`. In this case however, if you pass down `pageData` as props and you are given the loading indicator, `DataStore.getPageBySlug` must not work/must not return anything for the slug `home`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177833/discussion-between-terry-mitchell-and-tholle).